# Xamarin sample project not loading in Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community from the Xamarin website. but when I tried to open a Xamarin sample project, it is showing as unavailable in Solution Explorer.

I really don't know why I am unable to open the project with IDE downloaded from Xamarin website.

How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: What sample project are you opening?

Comment: I am opening this project https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app

Comment: Can you provide me with your version info by going to `Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info` and pasting it in a gist (https://gist.github.com)?

Comment: Follow these steps to see if you are missing something that needs to be installed..

- In Control Panel, open Programs and Features, choose the Xamarin item, and click Change.
- In the setup wizard for Xamarin that appears, click Next and then Change.
- In the list of optional features to install, expand Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015, choose will be installed on local drive, and click Next to proceed with adding the feature.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt488769.aspx#missing

Comment: BytesGuy- My VS about info is at this link. http://textuploader.com/5wn42

Comment: Eclipsed4utoo - it is not showing Xamarin program in Programs and features , is it could be the reason ? if yes how to solve?

Comment: @PardeepKapoor Please see my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your version info from the comment link (textuploader.com/5wn42) indicates that you do not have the Xamarin Tools installed.

Once those are installed though, you may still see this symptom if you haven't told Visual Studio that the project is from a trusted source; and in this case, as a security precaution, Visual Studio will not open the project automatically.

In that case, you can right-click on the project and select "Reload Project", Visual Studio will prompt you with a warning / confirmation dialog. If you confirm that you want to load the project then it should load and you can work with it normally.

Screencast demo: http://screencast.com/t/R4F7KapOe77

Comment: Unfortunately there's a bug with either visual studio or xamarin where it will still not reload it.

Comment: @yams Given the age of the original question it might not be exactly the same cause. What version of Visual Studio are you running, and does it help if you manually reinstall Xamarin from this link?

http://dl.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.2.0.719.msi

Comment: I recently had it happen with a xamarin update with visual studio 2015 and had to manually remove the project from the solution then re-add it.  FUN TIMES LOL

Comment: @yams I do know when opening a project, like a sample from GitHub; Visual Studio will prompt you to confirm you want to open it as part of a security check; but occasionally if I just click through it the dialog the project won't be loaded; because it's easy to accidentally skip the dialog. If it's not that, then it might be a bug. If you can reliably reproduce the issue then you could file a bug report in https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after recovering from a BSOD (Blue-screen). Visual Studio complained about missing Xamarin (which was installed). I had to remove the .csproj.**user** file of the problematic project. This solved the issue.

Comment: THANK YOU! I just sent 2-3 hours reinstalling Xamarin multiple times, to no avail. Removing/renaming my csproj.user solved the problem.